Would a scientific theory of everything be falsifiable?
Would you have to redefine "scientific theory" if we had theory of everything?
What would that definition become?
On a side note to include another question to reduce the number of questions I compose.
Would a theory of everything, in principle, be able to determine everything past, present, and future?

You clarify your real concern in a comment:

How would it qualify as a theory of 'everything" if its predictions could be false?

Falsifiable means: there is some conceivable sequence of observations that, if they arose, would cause a reasonable, well-informed person to believe the theory is false. A theory is falsifiable even if this falsifying sequence of observations is impossible in this specific universe.
For example, suppose your theory says that electrons have charge -1. A falsifying observation would be, for example, if an electron shot past a positively charged sphere curves away from the sphere, in a way that can't be explained by any of the other forces of nature. Because we can conceive of this falsifying observation, your theory that electrons have charge -1 is falsifiable. But it can never actually be falsified, because the universe will never generate that falsifying observation, because the theory happens to be correct.
A true theory of everything explains and predicts everything that will ever arise in this universe, and can never be falsified because it is right. Nonetheless, it is certainly "falsifiable"; it predicts the exact outcome of every experiment, and if any experiment ever gave a different outcome, the theory of everything would be falsified. The only reason that doesn't happen is that the theory is right.
In other words, to say a theory is "falsifiable" is not quite the same as to say the theory can in practice be falsified. A falsifiable theory is one that can conceivably be falsified. If the theory is right, then in practice this falsification can never happen. Despite that, it's still "falsifiable."

If a true theory could conceivably be false then it would not be a true theory. A true theory would eliminate the inconceivable.

@8Mad0Manc8 What makes you think so? Probably every theory more than 150 years old was considered true and not conceivably false while practically none of them is considered true today.

@8Mad0Manc8: Re: "conceivably". The theory of gravity says that if I'm on Earth's surface and drop this golf ball, it'll fall at ~9.8 m/s/s. I can conceive of an experiment that would falsify (that aspect of) the theory of gravity: if I drop that golf ball and it launches itself down at 1,000 m/s/s, then the theory of gravity has a problem. That is: I can conceive of a way to falsify the (very probably correct) theory. Compare that to a theory that says the golf ball does whatever it feels like: there's no conceivable way to demonstrate that that (insane) theory is wrong; it's not falsifiable.

A true theory of everything would not necessarily (and, actually, most likely not!) predict everything. It would "explain" seemingly unrelated observations with underlying simpler principles, the way electromagnetism "explains" light and magnetism alike.

The distinction of 'falsifiable' in principle but can't be falsified in practice is an interesting one. I am sympathetic to the OP's idea that the truth should be so blindingly obvious when we know it that there is no way to think any different. But I suppose the universe wants us to have faith in it rather than just accepting without question :-) And the quotes around "explain" in @Peter-ReinstateMonica s comment help me understand why some people think science is a big crock : say something or don't but don't equivocate, right?

"A falsifiable theory is one that can conceivably be falsified." - I would add "...by an experiment we can actually hope to perform in the near future". Falsifiability isn't about philosophical purity, after all; it's about being able to check if we're wrong.

@Ray: Well, that's maybe a bit restrictive. There are theories about the past that can't be falsified by experiment, but could be falsified by other observations (such as the fossil record). There are theories about the distant future (such as heat death) that can't be directly observed at all, but follow logically from things that are falsifiable in the present.

@Kevin For the former, "make an observation and see if it agrees with the theory" is an experiment, at least in the broad sense that I mean here. For the latter, the theory had better make other predictions that can be tested by experiment if we're to believe what it says about the things we can't test. It's fine if not every prediction the theory makes is immediately testable, but some must be, and the ones that aren't need to follow from the same parts of the theory that predict the bits we can test. (And the weirder the untestable bits, the more bits need to be testable.)

To demonstrate the usefulness of falsifiability, here's a non-scientific theory of everything:

Things happen.

This applies to everything that happens in the universe, and there's no conceivable outcome where it could be false (in this theory "everything stays still" is also a thing that happens).
Even if the theory is always true, we aren't satisfied with that theory. There's nothing we can learn from it, there's nothing we can predict based from it. For any question, we can just start listing all conceivable answers and the theory can do nothing to separate between them. Every single conceivable outcome in every single conceivable situation is consistent with the theory.
The simplest way for a true theory to be even slightly useful is to rule out at least one conceivable outcome in at least one situation. That's also known as falsifiability.

From one of your comments:

If a true theory could conceivably be false then it would not be a true theory. A true theory would eliminate the inconceivable.

You appear to be using an incorrect definition of "true".
For a theory to be true, its predictions must always be consistent with actual reality. That's all. Our ability to imagine a conceptual hypothetical of it being false is irrelevant, because the hypothetical is not reality. Only the actual physical reality of the universe that we exist in matters for whether or not a theory is true.
For a theory to be falsifiable, it must make predictions that can be tested and validated. This requires that we could conceive a hypothetical scenario in which the theory would be false. It specifically does not require that any such hypothetical scenario matches reality.
These definitions are fully compatible and do not conflict in any way. All that's required for a theory to be both true and falsifiable at the same time is that all hypotheticals in which it would be false do not match reality.

The term theory of everything (TOE) has been coined for a theory “that fully explains and links together all aspects of the universe. Finding a theory of everything is one of the major unsolved problems in physics.” See Theory of Everything.

The present challenge of unification is a theory which combines the
General Theory of Relativity with Quantum Mechanics (QM) to a theory
of Quantum Gravity. At the moment there are two candidates Loop
Quantum Gravity and String Theory. Until now neither of the two has
reached the status of an accepted physical theory.
It is not
visible that such a theory had to change the concept of a scientific
theory. If you do not agree, why do you think so? But it would introduce new fundamental physical
concepts.
Also I do not see a reson why TOE would not be falsifiable. Just the opposite: The domain of possible contradicting observation would be even bigger.
IMO it there is no reason to expect that TOE is possible: History
shows that progress in physics is often connected with new areas of
investigation, e.g. detecting new kinds of forces in a higher range
of energy. Bluntly speaking: Each solved question creates two new
open questions.

Also I do not expect that we will have a unification according to which
“everything past, present, and future” is determined: To our present
knowledge QM has an intrinsic indeterminism.

To speculate of a theory of everything in the sense that it explains
all phenomena - not only in the domain of physics - seems to me a
kind of megalomania. Here we enter the field of speculation similar
to theological speculations about an almighty and omniscient  god.



Yes I agree it is a question that arises between the difference in determining the truth and in the speculation of faith as being the truth.

"all phenomena - not only in the domain of physics" but all phenomena are ultimatly the result of physics. Even psychology is, at the very base, about neurons sending signals to each other. Every phenomenon can be reduced to physics, though most of the time it is not practical to do so, because that level is not relevant. However if you had a "theory of everything" in physics (and enough computational power) you could solve all problems of all other fields (like in this example psychology) with it.


Would a scientific theory of everything be falsifiable?

Yes of course, or it would not be a scientific theory.
It would at the very least need to contain some predictions that no other theory had made yet, and some kind of recipe of how to verify those predictions.
It may well be that we will never be able to actually test the prediction – the required experiments might just be too hard for us –  but that wouldn't change whether we'd consider it scientific or not. It took many years or in some cases decades for some of the predictions of General Relativity or Quantum Mechanics to be experimentally verified; they were no less scientific for it.

Would a theory of everything, in principle, be able to determine everything past, present, and future?

No.
A Theory of Everything, or – as an intermediate step – a Grand Unified Theory does not mean that you plug in some values and it predicts the future, or explains the past, in macroscopic terms.
To quote that article: a GUT...

...is any model in particle physics that merges the electromagnetic, weak, and strong forces (the three gauge interactions of the Standard Model) into a single force at high energies.

... and a ToE would be a

singular, all-encompassing, coherent theoretical framework of physics that fully explains and links together all aspects of the universe.

No more, no less. It is hard to tell what exactly we as humanity can achieve once we have it, but it is unlikely that there will be immediate SciFi achievements like time travel, wormholes, anti-gravity or anything like that. We will probably be able to solve some very deep questions (i.e., what does it actually, physically, mean to have a singularity inside a black hole), but the solution will likely be so incredibly theoretical that your regular layman will understand it as little as they do most quantum-mechanical aspects as of today.
The new theory must by force contain all the old theories, especially General Relativity and Quantum Mechanics (within the regimes where they are applicable). Especially QM has a lot of randomness inside as far as we know today (i.e., it is based on probability fields with inbuilt uncertainty, which have been confirmed experimentally for decades now). All of this is unlikely to simply go away. Even if all randomness is somehow removed by the GUT or ToE (which is only possible if reality is not, in fact, random at the lowest level – which is an unsolved question), then it is very likely that actually calculating anything with it will for the foreseeable future be incredibly difficult for more than a handful of elementary particles, if at all.
On the grand scale of things, even if we have all the formulas, even the basic Three Body Problem will likely not become easier to solve just because we have a GUT/ToE, making even the simplest predictions about how larger planetary/solar/galactic systems develop over a long time as impossible as before.
So the lay scientific-oriented news outlets would probably have a field day for a few weeks, and a great many books would be written to explain all the new findings to the general public, but afterwards it would likely be "back to normal" for most non-professional theoretical physicists.

The "theory of everything(TOE)" and the "grand unified theory(GUT)" are two different things though. The very wiki page you linked reads a bit further down "Thus, GUTs are often seen as an intermediate step towards a TOE." I'd argue that whether or not the TOE would theoretically able to predict the future or calculate the past would depend on whether all formulars in that theory are fully deterministic.

True enough, @datacube, thanks for pointing that out. The spirit of the answer does not change, but I have added the ToE to it.

But practically the future could still not be accuratly predicted because for an accurate prediction the calculation would have to include the entire universe. But you can't include the entire universe in a simulation (that is smaller than the universe itself) because that simulation would have to include itself as well, recursively an infinite amount of times.

Yes, I think I have included that point in my answer (without a very concrete reasoning - we don't even need to include the entire universe for this to be impossible if QM processes are truly probabilistic on the lowest level).

@datacube That's why I said in principle and not in practice. The universe is determinable it'd just be we cannot determine it in practice. Chaos theory and all, plus the recursiveness a computer model including itself in that calculation.


Would a scientific theory of everything be falsifiable?

In a comment below, you say you are using Popper's conception of what makes something a scientific theory. For Popper, a theory is scientific if it can in principle be falsified.
Therefore, under the conception of "scientific theory" you are using, a scientific theory of everything would be falsifiable by any observation inconsistent with the theory's prediction.
Presumably, such a theory of everything would make predictions about many mundane things:

trajectories of ballistic objects
orbits of planets
nuclear chemistry
path of light
behaviour of elementary particles
etc.

Any of these predictions would be susceptible to falsification.

How would it qualify as a theory of 'everything" if its predictions could be false?

Karl Poppers definition. Your argument is not sound.

Yes, you are right. Karl Poppers definition would mean that if you determined a scientific theory of everything that comes within that definition then that definition it would have to be falsifiable. If it were falsifiable and new evidence came to light that would question the validity of that scientific theory of everything. Then the definition 'everything ' is as my question intended, creates a logical paradox. Everything means everything, past, present and future. If that could be proven false then it was never a true scientific theory or any other theory you can define.

If you asked Popper: Sure. Because in order to be a scientific theory (of whatever, including everything), it would need to be falsifyable.
Being falsifiable does not mean that it has to be wrong, all it means is that it must make testable predictions. So a simple way to visiualize that might be that at first you make lots of measurements that result in a large series of data points. Idk if you measure the location of a driving car, you might put up a list of it's x-coordinates vs the time coordinate.
After you've done that you plot your discrete data (each measurement is just one point and no matter how many you've taken they are not connected) and try to fit a continuous function onto it. For example you could say: x = velocity_x * time.
Now where previously you only had data points for where you completed a measurement, now, due to the function being continuous, you also have data for times that you have not yet measured. So these data points would be your predictions for what would happen at these time if you were to measure or have measured.
So being falsifiable means that you could do the test and actually both compute and measure what you would expect to happen at a certain time and what actually does happen at that time and if the two are roughly in agreement (within an acceptable margin of error around the expected value), you could be content that for now your theory seems to be working, while if you'd see a drastic discrepancy, you'd have much less justified believe in the usefulness of your theory.
Now for a theory of everything we might turn to a more simplified universe, for example a large map of Conway's Game of Life.
It's fun because there's a lot of stuff happening, things are moving, there is seemingly interaction between different structures and whatnot and if you had no idea what is happening you could probably come up with various theories.
However if you investigate or read further you see it's all based on a set of very few rules:

Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if by underpopulation.
Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overpopulation.
Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.

So within this simple universe this would be a theory of everything as everything that can happen in this universe is a result of an initial condition and the application of these rules. And as you could predict what the next step would look like (using that theory), it would also be falsifiable, for example if the next step looked differently than predicted.
Now if you had the computing power you could look far into the future, but the past is somewhat unknown, given simple examples, for example looking at a periodic pattern and not being able to tell whether that is the 1st or 100000001st iteration or any one in between, before or beyond. Or if your pattern starts with a single cell somewhere, that cell will be dead in the next move, but the absence of a cell doesn't confirm or deny that there had been a life cell present in the step before.
Also while you technically know everything there is to know in that universe, this universe implements a turing machine and is subject to the halting problem so you can't create an algorithm that for all inputs tells you whether it will stop or evolve forever.
Now there have at times been ideas that our universe could also be rather simple and that if you'd know the location and momentum of every particle and could thus extrapolate their trajectory via classical mechanics you could predict past present and future. At least a supernatural demon having access to these coordinates all at ones and having the computational power to do it in time could: Laplace's demon
However reality showed itself to be more complicated. With irreversibility, the inability to even measure these properties, fragility with respect to initial condition, properties that can only be measured probabilistically and so on.
Also even if you had a theory of everything that could explain the smallest things completely and could build everything from there you'd still have a problem with computing that in time. Like try to do biology by explaining that by the underlying chemical processes which you derive from the physical properties of the atomic and subatomic particles, of which you might have in the order of 600,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 per gram (I hope I didn't screw up in the order of magnitude but you can get confused with 6*10^23). So yeah even a theory of everything probably has limits to being useful and so different disciplines are likely going to stay even if they could be reduced to something more fundamental.

Your issue is one of the definition of falsifiability.
Very basically it would be verified yet falsifiable if it makes predictions that COULD be either true or false but ends up making the correct predictions each time.
A "theory of everything" would need to accurately describe whatever you are referring to as "everything".  It would be falsifiable if those descriptions are not necessarily already assumed or true without the theory.
So, if such a theory were offered, and you used such a theory to make any prediction in any situation where the outcome was otherwise uncertain, it should get the prediction right instead of wrong.

This should help:

Per Popper, a scientific theory is always falsifiable.
Theory of everything (ToE) doesn't automatically mean "scientific theory of everything" (SToE). We already have thousands of monotheistic god hypothesis, which are not considered scientific even though most are falsifiable.
"Would a theory of everything, in principle, be able to determine everything past, present, and future?" - That is definitely an expectation. As of today, ToE is stuff of speculation, not science.



Would a theory of everything, in principle, be able to determine everything past, present, and future?

Almost certainly not. Your language is a little unclear here, but there are several different concepts involved:

A theory that provides explanations for everything, and allows predictions of the results of experiments.

A theory that allows predictions of all future events, given sufficient information.

A theory that allows predictions of all future events, without extraordinary amounts of information.


The first is what a scientific "theory of everything" would be.
The second would in principle be fulfilled by a scientific theory of everything, but this would not apply in practice. It's impractical, for example, to have sufficient information about the motion of every molecule of gas in Earth's atmosphere to allow prediction of precisely when the next tropical storm to affect Florida will happen, or just where it will start.
The third would require that the universe is deterministic to a degree that we  have no evidence for, and a lot of evidence against. If it were that deterministic and we somehow learned to read its script in advance, that would raise serious questions about the nature of reality.
